# Gauss elimination. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Gaussian elimination with back sub:

So my starting matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\\2 & 1 & -3 & 4
\\2 & 0 & 2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}

multiply the 2nd and 3rd row by -1 * (first row):

\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\\0 & 3 & -5 & 6
\\0 & 2 & 0 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}

then add -1(third row) to the 2nd row->

\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\\0 & 1 & -5 & 2
\\0 & 2 & 0 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}

add -2(2nd row) to the third row -> 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\\0 & 1 & -5 & 2
\\0 & 0 & 10 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

But then this seems to have no solution because $10z = 0$.... ugh

**EDIT**

As I was writing this, it occurred to me that $z = 0$, $y = 2$, $x = 1$. Is that right?

Comment: Your edit is correct

Comment: In general, if you get an incorrect answer, find your error by "bisection" ... take one of your steps from the middle, plug in your incorrect answer, and see if it works.  This will tell you whether your mistake is before or after that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

Check that $(1,2,0)$ is a solution and also since the rank is $3$, there is a unique solution.

$10z=0 \implies z=0$, substitute that to other equations, we easily get $y=2$ and then $x-y+0 = -1 \implies x-2=-1 \implies x=1$.

Comment: What do you mean the rank is 3 there is a unique solution? can you clarify?

Comment: you do not have any non-pivot columns, every column ($3$ of them) are pivot columns hence there is a unique solution.

Comment: what's a pivot column

Comment: In the case of Gaussian elimination, those leading non-zero entries are the pivot elements, those columns corresponding to the pivot elements are pivot columns. [might be of interest](http://www.tkiryl.com/teaching/la/les090503web.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your way to obtain the RREF, we can proceed as follow

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\\2 & 1 & -3 & 4
\\2 & 0 & 2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}\stackrel{R3-R2}\to \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\\2 & 1 & -3 & 4
\\0 & -1 & 5 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}\stackrel{R2-2\cdot R1}\to \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\\0 & 3 & -5 & 6
\\0 & -1 & 5 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}\stackrel{3\cdot R3+R2}\to \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\\0 & 3 & -5 & 6
\\0 & 0 & 10 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and since the matrix is full rank (we have three pivots) we have an unique solution that is

- from the third row: $z=0$
- from the second row: $y=2$
- from the first row: $x=1$

Comment: its wrong, you made a mistake in the first step when you tried to add -1(2nd row) to the third row

Comment: @Jwan622 Yes just noticed and fixed meanwhile! Thanks

Comment: @Isham Yes, now it should be ok. Thanks

Comment: @Isham Ok that's was really a typo! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a more systematic method:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
2 & 1 & -3 & 4\\
2 & 0 & 2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 3 & -5 & 6\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets R_2-2R_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3-2R_1 \end{aligned}
\\ &\to
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -5/3 & 2\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets\tfrac{1}{3}R_2
\\ &\to
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -5/3 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 10/3 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3-2R_2
\\ &\to
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -5/3 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets\tfrac{3}{10}R_3
\\ &\to
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
&& \begin{aligned} R_2 &\gets R_2+\tfrac{5}{3}R_3 \\ R_1&\gets R_1-R_3\end{aligned}
\\ &\to
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_1\gets R_1+R_2
\end{align}
The solution, which is explicit when the RREF is reached, is
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}